# html programming

Tags: html, sublime-text, atom.io

which program is the best for html programming?
i'm starting html programming and don't know which program to use?
by search I've found out atom and sublime are two of the popular ones but sublime is not free and atom is a bit heavy and needs a really good computer.
any other choice do you recommend or are these good and if so which one?

Comment: Sublime isn't "free", but there is no time limit on using it before paying.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is a free, open source editor for web design and development built on top of web technologies such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The project was created and is maintained by Adobe, and is released under an MIT License.

Brackets has almost the same features as Adobe Dreamweaver. With the  *Live Preview* feature of Brackets , each and every change you make in either your CSS or HTML file in the active project is previewed instantly in an external web browser.

- Inline editors

  Instead of jumping between file tabs, Brackets lets you open a window into the code you care about most. Want to work on the CSS that applies to a specific ID? Put your mouse cursor on that ID, press Command ( <kbd>⌘</kbd> ) / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and Brackets will show you all the CSS selectors with that ID in an inline window so you can work on your code side-by-side without any popups.
- Live Preview

  Get a real-time connection to your browser. Make changes to CSS and HTML and you'll instantly see those changes on screen. Also see where your CSS selector is being applied in the browser by simply putting your cursor on it. It's the power of a code editor with the convenience of in-browser dev tools.
- Preprocessor support

  Work with preprocessors in a whole new way. Brackets is one of the best code editors for preprocessors out there. With Brackets you can use *Quick Edit* and *Live Highlight* with your LESS and SCSS files which will make working with them easier than ever.

Answer (score 0):

What is your operation system?

If you are on windows, you can use **CoffeeCup HTML editor** too.
it is dedicated to html-css and not another language and can insert some tag graphically into your code.

But if you are on Linux, i Prefer VIM as my editor because it is so fast. just equip it by some plugins such as [Emmet.vim](https://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/)